# use window.location="http://www.example.com" instead of whole index page in phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I am a beginner to phonegap and want to make an app for my website by providing

window.location="http://www.example.com"

instead of all the html code of my website index page.
But I still want to use the cordova features like isMobile or isMobileApp in my application.
Is there any way I can proceed with this type of situation or I will have to make it through my index page.

Also,is there any way to dynamically change the index.html of my app through javascript.

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, might this plugin can do what you want.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html This plugin  load a complete HTML web page on your application Or Use Iframe.

If you want to change content dynamically from phonegap, you need to use Ajax with php or  any of your choice of server side language like .net